# Does $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac{\int_0^\epsilon f}{\epsilon^{1/q}} = 0$ hold for all $f\in L^p[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Fix $1 < p < \infty$ and choose $f\in L^p[0,1]$.
Let $q = \frac{p}{p-1}$ denote the Hölder conjugate of $p$.

I am trying to prove the following statement:
$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac{\int_0^\epsilon f}{\epsilon^{1/q}} = 0$$

$$\rule{10cm}{1pt}$$

My attempt:
Hoping to apply L'Hôpital's Rule, I took derivatives of top and bottom
$$\frac{q\cdot F'(\epsilon)}{\epsilon^{-1/p}}$$

where $F'(\epsilon) = \frac{d}{d\epsilon}\int_0^\epsilon f$.
I know that $F'(\epsilon) = f$ a.e. on $[0,1]$ and I also know that if $|f|$ grows at least as fast as $\epsilon^{-1/p}$ as $\epsilon \to 0^+$, then $f \notin L^p[0,1]$. But I'm having trouble using those facts to prove something like
$$\limsup_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\frac{|F'(\epsilon)|}{\epsilon^{-1/p}} = 0$$
For example, is it possible that $|F'(\epsilon)| \geq \epsilon^{-1/p}$ on a small enough set that $F' \in L^p[0,1]$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not going to get this from L'Hopital. Holder shows that $$\left|\int_0^\epsilon f\right|\le\left(\int_0^\epsilon|f|^p\right)^{1/p}\left(\int_0^\epsilon1^q\,dt\right)^{1/q}, $$so
$$\left|\frac{\int_0^\epsilon f}{\epsilon^{1/q}}\right|\le\left(\int_0^\epsilon|f|^p\right)^{1/p}.$$Now apply dominated convergence...

Answer (score 3):

Holder’s inequality implies that 
$$\left|\int_0^\epsilon f\right|\leq \int_0^\epsilon |f|\leq\left(\int_0^\epsilon |f|^p\right)^{\frac1p}\left(\int_0^\epsilon 1\right)^{\frac 1q}=\left(\int_0^\epsilon |f|^p\right)^{\frac1p}\epsilon^{\frac1q}.$$
Finally use DCT to show that
$$\int_0^\epsilon |f|^p\to 0\ \ \text{as }\epsilon\to0^+.$$

Comment: Right. About the typesetting - "edit" my answer to look at the TeX; note how \left...\right makes it look nicer.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Fixed now. Thanks for your comment.